# stress testing an application and failing at database connection

Tags: postgres, tcp

I currently have a nodejs(nestjs) app, and a postgres database. The database has a maximum connections available as 1700, and I'm trying to spike a 1000 request in a single instance of a second.  The test takes about 4m to complete in which the app/database resources aren't consumed very much (CPU/memory), and I analyze the database continuously , the connection pool isn't exhausted at all, and even if it would, I would expect a different error(e.g. too many clients already). The error I'm getting is like this:

```
2023-01-31T08:46:17.025832753Z at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
2023-01-31T08:46:17.027421325Z [31m[Nest] 52 - [39m01/31/2023, 8:46:17 AM [31m ERROR[39m [38;5;3m[ExceptionsHandler] [39m[31mconnect ETIMEDOUT 20.111.121.122:5432[39m
2023-01-31T08:46:17.027480928Z Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 20.111.121.122:5432
2023-01-31T08:46:17.027490729Z at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16)
2023-01-31T08:46:17.027495029Z at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
2023-01-31T08:46:17.029191106Z [31m[Nest] 52 - [39m01/31/2023, 8:46:17 AM [31m ERROR[39m [38;5;3m[ExceptionsHandler] [39m[31mconnect ETIMEDOUT 20.111.121.122:5432[39m
2023-01-31T08:46:17.029645727Z Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 20.111.121.122:5432
2023-01-31T08:46:17.029700829Z at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16)
```

The only thing I can decipher so far from this log, due to the port number in the `20.111.121.122:5432` which belongs to postgres, is something to do with the app not being able to establish a connection with the database.

Currently I would say a 20%-30% failure are happening due to this, in a 1000 request spike. Under normal load it mostly doesn't happen.

So, my question is, if it is normal for a app or database to drop out such connections even though resources are available? Or should this be more of a problem on the programmer's side? Am I misunderstanding the log above?  Or are there possible solutions to this?  Please provide me some insight on this especially for postgres database.

EDIT:

```
This is how I cache the connection for each db:  
    cache = {};
    schemas = ['sche1', 'sche2', 'sche3',......, 'sch4']
    db = ['db1', 'db2', 'db3', 'db4']
    for(let i=0; i< schemas.length; i++){
    baseConnection = {
      host: '23',
      db: selectAppropriateDb(schemas[i]);
      port: 5432,
      user: selectUser(schemas[i])
      poolSize: 20 
      password: <pwd> 
      }
    const dataSource = new DataSource(baseConnection);
    cache[schemas[i]]= await dataSource.initialize();
    }
```

In k6, I just create 1000 Virtual users, and send a request like:

```
http.get('testroute', getTokenForIthSchema(uniqueId))
```

Comment: I heard you say that on one client host you have a single nestjs process, multi-threaded, that is hitting PG on 5432 on another server host. You did not show us the code you used to stimulate the server, so I will assume it initiated new TCP connections as fast as possible without awaiting success status, in other words, no back pressure on offered load. In which case, the system behaved correctly, and the logged messages are expected. The server kernel queue filled with unanswered TCP connections. I didn't hear you say anything about that queue's observed size or configured limit.

Comment: @J_H , I've added the code, but, it's a simple http request that is made by 1000 virtual users . Above you've mentioned `no back pressure on offered load In which case, ... and the logged messages are expected. The server kernel queue filled with unanswered TCP connections. ...anything about that queue's observed size or configured limit.` . Could you explain a bit more please. Also, the only configurable parameter exposed I have is the poolsize, what is the queue that you have mentioned, could you please explain or let me know if there is a way to observe this? (A tool or command perhaps?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>   poolSize: 20
> ```

> In k6, I just create 1000 Virtual users

You mentioned "k6" which I am not yet familiar with.

I *think* I heard you say that, rather than using a
(multi-threaded) single process on a single client host,
you asked k6 to use a large number of servers to send offered load.

K6 produces 1000 virtual users, each of them able to
create up to the pool limit of 20 TCP connections to the postgres server.

In other words, if they were looping through a bunch of requests,
your virtual users could simultaneously keep 20,000 TCP connections
to port 5432 open. Hitting a single server that has 8 cores.

Flow control ("back pressure") is going to be an issue here.
Your PG server can only do so much.
When it gets a [Dirac impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response)
of offered load, it will not respond infinitely fast.

Postgres is a daemon, running in user space.
It issued a [bind(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/bind)
call on 5432, and a subsequent
[listen(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/listen).
Essentially, it informed the kernel that it is interested
in phone calls arriving on 5432, and the kernel agreed to forward such calls.
There is a critically important parameter:

```
int listen(int sockfd, int backlog);
```

Typically `backlog` is less than 30.
I note that 30 is less than 1000.
(EDIT: It turns out that some daemons default to values close to a hundred,
or even more, but much less than a thousand.)

> The backlog argument defines the maximum length to which the queue of pending connections for sockfd may grow. If a connection request arrives when the queue is full, the client may receive an error ...

You can use `$ netstat -an`, `$ ss -it; ss -lt` or `# lsof` to monitor the kernel's TCP
[PCB](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/tcpip-illustrated/020163354X/ch22.html)
protocol control blocks.
The key thing is that, for zero client errors,
postgres (or any daemon) needs to notice an incoming phone call
and pick up the phone with
[accept(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/accept)
*before* the backlog is exceeded.
Once the queue is full, new calls just get dropped on the floor.
Which eventually (after client timeout) results in messages
like what you see in the log.

---

Let QPS be queries per second, where a query is the
very simple "SELECT MAX(id) FROM some_table;"

Here are some basic facts about your DB server that you really
ought to know:

1. Using a single persistent TCP connection how many QPS does a single client host with a WHILE TRUE ... loop achieve? This is closed loop.
2. As number of threads (or processes) increases, how many QPS does that same single client achieve? Does it saturate the DB server?
3. Now increase the number of client hosts. What number of WHILE loops, across what number of clients, will saturate the server? How many QPS in aggregate?
4. Now switch to the much harder problem of: create connection, do simple query, close connection. This is open loop, where `backlog` becomes relevant. How many QPS does a single client achieve?
5. Using the number of client hosts found in (3.), how many QPS do those clients achieve?

Running experiment (1.) is trivially easy.

By the time you get to (5.) you want to model clients as
[Poisson arrivals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process),
since that has the desirable property of being "memoryless".
Visitors know nothing of one another.
They are modeled with a single parameter lambda,
which lets you talk about expected number of arrivals
over the course of a second or a month for individuals
or for the whole population.

Bump up the load to a given server, saturate it, and note the value of lambda.
Now use 2x or 10x that value.
It's a sure thing the server won't keep up, and you'll be looking at errors.

Web servers, such as google for the initial page of search results,
are open loop -- if they slow down their response that won't
slow the visitor arrival rate in the short term.
Database servers typically are closed loop -- we assume that client
hosts such as web servers maintain long-lived TCP connection,
and that slowing down SELECT responses will slow down the
offered rate of SQL queries.

With an understanding of all that for your particular setup,
you will be in a good position to determine how many simultaneous
(and long lived) TCP connections your DB server can offer
your various web servers. If you go above that, bad things
will happen. If web servers continually tear down short
lived connections and re-create new TCP connections, bad
things will happen.

Additionally, you will want to understand how actual queries
from a realistic workload perform differently from that
very simple query above.

---

Sending 1000 simultaneous connection requests to a single host
is not a communication protocol. It is not a benchmark.
It is a recipe for disaster, as reflected in the logs you shared.

Presumably you wish to measure *throughput*,
the number of useful app-level events of interest per second.
A failed connect attempt is not adding to the business's bottom
line, it is not useful. You want to measure events that actually
make it through the e2e system. So start small, with 10 virtual users,
and dial it up until you just barely break things. Now you
[know](https://web.archive.org/web/20140224054013im_/http://assets.amuniversal.com/0266da64250b102d94d7001438c0f03b)
what the server capacity is.
This is more useful than knowing "capacity is less than a thousand
[open loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-loop_controller)
users."
Leonard Kleinrock's "Queuing Systems" points out that
a closed loop client-server system will never be overwhelmed,
it will merely make clients wait longer for an answer.
Open loop flash mobs hitting a web site or PG server
can easily overwhelm `backlog` and other limits,
resulting in user visible errors rather than
user visible delays.

Benchmarking is hard.
Decide on your benchmarking goals.
Write them down.
Execute on them.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear about k6. K6 simulates only real world users, so, it's sending http requests to the server (nestjs api). It's the nestjs api that is actually responsible for creating a pool, so, for 200 schemas, I observed this even if I had a max poolsize of 5, creating max of 200 X5 = 1000 active connections at a time. . But, you have mentioned the backlog size is important, and since it exceeds 30 at a certain point in time, it throws the error? Does this also happen when the application maintains a connection pool and reuses the connection established?

Comment: Also, isn't 1000 users a pretty low traffic for a server staying up 24/7? I wonder if I'm doing something wrong with my application, how would people usually handle this much of traffic? I am currently using azure's postgres service, and it's a medium tier General purpose 4 core 16 gb postgres server, it should be able to handle at least this much of traffic when it's only under minimal load.

Comment: In step no 3 above could you please tell me what did you mean by saturate? Typically if connection timeout is increased, the requests would just end up waiting right?

Comment: In benchmarking, to "saturate" a SUT system-under-test is to keep increasing offered load until the point that no additional app-level throughput (transactions per second) is observed. Typically this corresponds to zero idle CPU cycles available on the server, or maxing out some queue's capacity or disk I/O or network bandwidth. Presenting higher offered load doesn't really let you learn anything further about the SUT. You could give it 2x or 100x what it's capable of and the best that could happen is you measure that constant throughput. More likely you actually measure decreasing throughput.

Comment: The motivation for using more than one client (i.e., step 3) is that a single client may or may not be powerful enough to saturate the SUT. With many client machines at our disposal, and a powerful network interconnect, we can _always_ find the breaking point which saturates the server. https://web.archive.org/web/20140224054013im_/http://assets.amuniversal.com/0266da64250b102d94d7001438c0f03b

Comment: As for the poolsize, do you think a formula to estimate given a spec of database, something like : Tn * (Cm — 1) + 1 i.e. threads * (connection max per thread - 1) + 1 , is usually a good estimate, or would you suggest the test above with the open connection? Or do you think there is a better test to determine pool size?

Comment: There _is_ a server bottleneck, somewhere. It is either in a configured queueing resource or memory or CPU or disk I/O or network capacity. It is possible that a formula like the one proposed could describe the bottleneck, but it is far from certain. Based on the technical measurements you have shared so far, you cannot yet quantify or locate the benchmark. Neither can we. Our understanding thus far is of [a meager and unsatisfactory kind](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/166961-when-you-can-measure-what-you-are-speaking-about-and).

Comment: um.... I'm afraid if I'm correct in understanding if I'm not clear enough? But, basically, I have an api that communicates with the database, and the api makes asynchronous requests, each request initiating a connection to the postgres database in azure. So, I just want some methodology that would help me determine an optimal poolsize. I don't really know how would I express that in numbers.

Comment: I described five steps towards better characterizing your server. The optimal pool size, meaning, pool size that gives highest throughput all other things being equal, is going to be workload dependent. You have an example workload, just ramp up the pool size while applying that workload. it is important that you start with a working system, for example, with a pool size of one or 10. Then continue to increase it until you see that it is no longer helping your throughput metric.

Comment: I wonder if you could explain which throughput would you mean? I started with poolSize of 5 and continued to increase to 20, but, when I see azure app insights, both the incoming request and outgoing requests from the web app have no effect.